# How to ensure a schema inside of a "oneOf" clause is matched at most once?

Tags: jsonschema

Given a schema like this:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "oneOf": [
      {"$ref": "#/definitions/foo"},
      {"$ref": "#/definitions/bar"},
      {"$ref": "#/definitions/baz"},
    ]
  },
  "definitions": {...}
}
```

how would I ensure that, for example, at most one item in the array matches the schema "foo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not apply a general cardinality constraint on array items as you request.
But depending on your business needs you could use on the following three alternatives:

First, if `foo` can ocurr at most once, you may consider to take it out of the array and add it as an optional property.

```
{
"type":"object",
"properties":{
"foo":{
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/foo"
        }
        "otherItems" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
                "oneOf" : [{
                        "$ref" : "#/definitions/bar"
                    }, {
                        "$ref" : "#/definitions/baz"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "definitions" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

Second, if no specific order is needed, you may also use an object instead of an array achieving similar structural constraints:

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "foo" : {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/foo"
        }
    },
    "additionalItems" : {
        "oneOf" : [{
                "$ref" : "#/definitions/bar"
            }, {
                "$ref" : "#/definitions/baz"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Last but not least, if you can enforce your clients to send the `foo` object in the first place of the array when it occurs, then the following schema would be the most close to yours:

```
{
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : [{
            "oneOf" : [{
                    "$ref" : "#/definitions/foo"
                }, {
                    "$ref" : "#/definitions/bar"
                }, {
                    "$ref" : "#/definitions/baz"
                },
            ]
        }

    ],
    "additionalItems" : {
        "oneOf" : [{
                "$ref" : "#/definitions/bar"
            }, {
                "$ref" : "#/definitions/baz"
            }
        ]
    }

}
```